# what is the use of 'u' with integers

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

Code here is to check if the input is 'x'. What it means when it's 23u, why can't we just write 23.

```
# define IS_X(a) (((unsigned)a | 32) - 97 == 23u)
```

Comment: Paranoia? It's just being specific about being unsigned. How is this any better than `a == 'x'`?

Comment: I was trying to understand the usage of 'u' and got this code online. I was wondering if 'u' with 23 is significant for some reason or using 23 is fine.

Comment: The code checks whether the input is `'x'` or `'X'` — it is a case-sensitive comparison assuming a code set based on ISO 8859 or ASCII; it is not aware of accents.  The `u` on the `23u` ensures that the RHS expression is unsigned.  But the LHS is going to be unsigned because of the cast, so the RHS would have been handled OK even without the `u` suffix.  You'll quite often find code that works but contains something that an out and out minimalist would find unnecessary (in this case, the `u` suffix — I could make a case for subtracting 96 and comparing with 24 since X is the 24th letter).

Comment: I said I could make a case for subtracting 96 and comparing with 24 since X is the 24th letter — even better would be `(((unsigned)(a) | 32) == 'x'`) — it is more nearly self-explanatory. The parentheses around the `(a)` macro argument are also a good idea — when you embed a macro argument in an arithmetic or logical expression, surround it with parentheses to avoid unexpected results, such as if the macro is invoked with `IS_X(flag == 19 ? c2 : c3)`, for example. The original code is an interesting mixture of paranoia (the `u` suffix) and amnesia (missing parentheses around `a` in expansion).

Comment: Nice explanation and optimization of code snippet @Jonathan Leffler , will use `(((unsigned)(a) | 32) == 'x')`

Comment: Likely one of two things is true: The code hardcodes 32, 97, and 23 because the author wanted to work with ASCII data regardless of the execution character set, or the author carelessly hardcoded character set values in a non-portable way. In the former case, you should not use `… == ' x'`, as that removes the hardcoding of the constants. In the latter case, you should not use `… | 32 …`, as that is not portable. For portable code, use `(tolower(a) == 'x')`.

Comment: (Pedantic: Reading the specification for `tolower`, it seems `tolower(toupper(a)) == 'x'` might be required to guarantee canonicalization of the character.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Can you justify your pedantic comment?  I see symmetry between [`tolower` and `toupper`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.2) and _If the argument is a character for which `isupper` is true and there are one or more corresponding characters, as specified by the current locale, for which `islower` is true, the `tolower` function returns one of the corresponding characters (always the same one for any given locale); otherwise, the argument is returned unchanged._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Suppose a locale has, say, formal X (which I will call X0), informal X (X1), formal x (x0), and informal x (x1). Then `tolower` must map X0 and X1 to x0 (or x1, but I will assume the former). However, `tolower` is specified to return its argument unchanged if `isupper` is not true, so `tolower('x1')` returns x1, not x0. By using `tolower(toupper(a))`, we get both x0 and x1 changed to one of X0 or X1, and then changed to x0.

Comment: It's my understanding that in some implementations a plain old `char` is signed, and in others it's unsigned. I suspect that the person who wrote this code has very definite views on which is correct.

Comment: @TimRandall: Their concern could be that `(a | 32) - 97` could overflow if `a` were `EOF`, and converting to `unsigned` guards against that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil wouldn't casting to `int` have the same effect? The comparison would still evaluate to false. But please don't take my above comment seriously. I don't like defines, I don't like magic numbers, and I particularly don't like the use of `|32`, so anything I say about this code is going to be snarky.

Comment: @Sbk3824 Instead of `(((unsigned)(a) | 32) == 'x')`, alternative `(((unsigned)(a) | ('X'^'x') == ('X'|'x'))`  avoids the magic number 32 yet relies on `x,X` differing by 1 bit - true in ASCII and EBCDIC.  Still not as good as `tolower(unsigned char)a)== 'x'`

Comment: @TimRandall: No, casting to `int` will not have the same effect. C does not specify what the value of `EOF` is, except that it is an `int` with a negative value. It could be, for example, `INT_MIN`. Suppose it were and we were working with 16-bit two’s complement `int`. Then `INT_MIN` is -32768, and `INT_MIN | 32` is -32736, and `(INT_MIN | 32) - 97` would be -32833 mathematically, which overflows `int` and has undefined behavior. By casting to `unsigned int`, there is never overflow, just wrapping with defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the use of 'u' with integers

With an *integer constant*, `'u'` and `'U'` insure the constant is `unsigned` (or `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long` when large).

---

> What it means when it's 23u,

```
# define IS_X(a) (((unsigned)a | 32) - 97 == 23u)
```

The `u` makes 23 an `unsigned int 23` rather than a `signed int 23`.  By doing so, the compare will be done in at least `unsigned` math.

Yet the left hand side `((unsigned)a | 32) - 97` result is `unsigned` and so the compare would have been `unsigned` anyways. [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431757/what-is-the-use-of-u-with-integers/52432933#comment91807232_52431757)

Some compilers/code checkers will warn of comparing an `unsigned` with an `int`.    By using `u`, both sides are the same type and quiet such warnings.

As to if a compiler should warn with `23` is a separate issue.

> why can't we just write 23.

Code could use `23` and risk an overly pedantic warning noted above.

---

From a macro perspective, good coding practice is to `()` each parameter usage:

```
// # define IS_X(a) (((unsigned)a | 32) - 97 == 23u)
//                          v-v
#define IS_X(a) (((unsigned)(a) | 32) - 97 == 23u)
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed to by chux and Jonathan Leffler, the result of `((unsigned)a | 32) - 97` is unsigned. It is possible that the programmer was using a compiler with very strict warning levels that complained about the comparison mixing unsigned and signed values. Forcing unsigned type for the second operand `23` with the `u` suffix might have removed this warning.

The macro is definitely fishy: `a` should be parenthesized in the expansion:

```
#define IS_X(a) (((unsigned)(a) | 32) - 97 == 23u)
```

The macro could have been written `((a) == 'x' || (a) == 'X')` but `a` would be evaluated twice in most cases, which the programmer wanted to avoid.

Since this macro only works for ASCII, I wonder why this much simpler alternative was not used:

```
#define IS_X(a)  (((a) | 32) == 'x')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you give, every number is converted to `unsigned int` because of the `unsigned` cast propagating through due to the usual arithmetic conversion rules; therefore, explicitly saying 23 is unsigned is unnecessary, and arguably uglier.

The 'u' suffix to integers is rarely needed. There are two reasons I can think of to use it.

1) If you are performing several operations on just constants, sometimes explicit unsigned behavior is exactly what you want. Take for instance `unsigned int x = 524289 * 4096;` Assuming 32 bit ints, the calculation will overflow the signed version, which is undefined behavior, but if we modify it thusly `unsigned int x = 524289u * 4096u;`, it will fit just fine in an `unsigned int`. Its behavior is also always defined. We could have just casted one the values, but I would argue this is clearer.

2) One word: warnings. A common compiler and linter warning complains whenever there is a comparison between a signed or unsigned integers, making

```
unsigned x = 3;
/* Do stuff */
if (x > 2) // Comparison of signed and unsigned integers
{
    /* Do something */
}
```

cause a warning, which may cause a failed compilation depending on how anal the build requirements are. There can also be warnings for performing bitwise operations on signed integers, so your linter might complain about this:

```
int roundup16 (int x)
{
    return ((x - 1) | 0xf) + 1;
}
```

which returns x, rounded up to the next multiple of 16.